# Technical ways to protect SPA code in production

Tags: javascript, ember.js, single-page-application

What technical solution do you setup to have your application source code at least not wide openly distributed to the rest of the world in production ?

Some may argue this code has no big value, but having the app's object model fully documented is a real competitive disadvantage, IMO.

Any ideas, arguments, patterns you can share with us?

#### Edit / Precision

I must have been unclear: The idea is not to hide app from allowed users (in which case, I agree, obfuscation is largely sufficient). What I mean is to **not serve** the app at all **while** the user is **not logged in**.

Answer (score 5):

You should not build your spa like its shown in some popular tutorials and videos. Don't use libs like breeze.js that expose your db entity schema and even your queries on your entity objects.  Don't serve more info, data, fields, rows etc than needed for the specific view. Don't carry your business rules on to the client javascript, hide them in serverside apis, and call them via ajax and just serve the result on the client, do most of your complex validation on the serverside ajax apis do just do very basic rules on the client javascript, leave those things that give you a competitive edge behind the serverside web apis. A clever written enterprise spa that serves some line of business should ideally just be the necessary user interface with the great user experience, nothing more, no data processing or heavy calculations on the client javascript please, or anyone could steal your business.

Comment: Thx @Kobi for this contribution. There are indeed insightful suggestions. On the other hand, it does reduce the interest of offline support, but I agree on all your points.

Answer (score 1):

In my projects, I just minify CSS and JS codes, so it doesn't include the comments on production. But hey, you're right, the code itself has no big value. I know a real programmer can recreate what I made just by looking at it - so why bother. Plus, nobody wants to re-invent the wheel. Trying to hide them will not give anything other than extra work.

So just minify them to increase performance and reduce HTTP requests. Also if you use handlebars (since Ember.js is tagged), you can pre-compile it too.

If you really want to hide everything, you can always revert to conventional server side app (like conventional php) without any javascript.

**EDIT**: Now I understand your question. You can make a simple page without javascript for users to login, and, when login is successful, redirect them to your ember application.

Comment: Thx for your response. Indeed, minification is done, but the end of your answer is the beginning of the clue I'd like to dig... except that __a server-side app is a no brainer!__ :-)

The question is: how do you achieve that, personnaly. We have a few ideas, here, but would like to challenge them w/ other deployments...

Comment: Sure, you can always pre-compile your handlebars templates. I use grunt-ember-templates, which compiles all .hbs files into a single .js file. https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (or fortunately) javascript can never be completely hidden from the end user as browsers give access to inspect files that are loaded for the page. The best thing you can do is make the code hard to read by minifying it. This is a good idea even if you don't want to hide your source as it will allow the javascript file to load faster raising the performance of your website.

Minifying basically strips your file of all comments, spaces and puts everything on a continous line. It'll look similar to [this](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js)

There are many different ways to minify javascript. [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) may be one of the easiest ways that i've found. You can create a task to minify your javascript and even have it watch your file so if you save it, it will minify it into an external file each time.

In an opinion, if there was ever a reason to not have a mentality to hide your code, it would be to encourage growth in the development industry and let other people gain knowledge off your code.

Comment: Thx for your reply, but you can see my comment: minification/obfuscation is not the real aim of the question.

Comment: So you just want to know how to make a login page? Or you want the code to be hidden(minified/obfusticated) if they aren't logged in? and if they are logged in you don't want to minify/obfusticate it?

Comment: In fact, I would like to have external thinkings about solutions people setup to serve the JS assets in a private way (if so!). Because usually, the static assets are served publicly, so available to the world, even when there is a login page, even not referencing them.

_(Without any consideration of minification/obfuscation which are, for me, another topic)_

Comment: I think what you want is not possible. The only thing I could think is that your login page would only reference a small set of javascript for the login page to run, then they won't see other javascripts that aren't suppose to be viewed by non-users. Would that work?

Comment: That's exactly the idea. My question is then "What best practices would you suggest?". BTW, I just found this (small) thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/USMt8UaH0PE which is exactly what I aim to do... I will dig this idea, by default, if nothing better comes out

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to use some sort of uglifier to just make the code harder to decipher.  If the code is available to be run in a browser then it's also available to be inspected.

Comment: Thx, but see my comment :-)

The availability is precisely the issue. I would like to be able not to expose the code to unauthorized users.